# Input percentage data from a GUI excel

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, input

Today I'm asking you for some help.
So here is the problem.
I have created a GUI form on Excel and some questions should be filled with fixed percentage (only 10%, 20%, 30% ...) so I used for that a dropdown list that shows the percentages allowed to be used and the user only has to select the proper percentage.
Now the problem, is that the dropdown list shows the percentages but when I select a value, it shows decimals like 0.2, 0.1, 0,4, and not as a percentage.
Also, when the values are inserted in the my excel file (my data base), they are shown as decimals too  which is my problem.
Please if you have any ideas that could help me, i would be very thankful.

Comment: For your Sheet: `0.2` and `20%` are the same values, just displayed differently. Format your cells as Percent and the value is displayed correctly

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't work, now actually i did something great, i changed the dropdown list so that I only have whole numbers not percentages, and in the code I did this :
' InputStatutAvancement =  InputStatutAvancement & "%" '
which makes appear a percentage, and in the data base I changed the column's format, and apparently it works pretty good.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.